# Can message name end in Request?

Tags: ros, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I defined a message ConfirmRequest.msg and that did not work properly. Catkin did not generate the message automatically and when I forced it by explicitly listing the message  I got problem with linking.

So is "Request" a forbidden ending of a message name? If so is that documented somewhere?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/90211/can-message-name-end-in-request?/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2013-10-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think there's anything explicitly preventing it. However I'd recommend against using that as it will conflict with similarly named service definitions.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1